# Which English writer community website to give the free feedback on a writing content?

Tags: creative-writing, style, community, ghostwriter

I'm interested in becoming an associate ghostwriter/semi-writer as part of freelance work. So, I want to find a group of English writers (online community) to review a writing content and give me the feedback respectively. My writing skill is satisfactory but I just need to know their opinions. No proofreading needed, just read the short paragraph. Sometimes, I would be appreciated it that a few warm-hearted writers could do the minimal proofreading.

Answer (score 2):

Scribophile is a community of writers. You post work and other people comment on it. It is mostly fiction but not exclusively.

Unless you pay, you have to critique other people's writing in order to get them to critique yours.

Critiquing other people's work is a good way of improving your own skills.

Comment: I never heard of it but thank you. A website seems promising and I will try it. My writing content is almost non-fiction that relates to an area of business and digital technology.